# Auto-generate JPA XML mappings from clean Java classes / POJOs using library/tool

Tags: java, jpa, pojo

I am currently working for a client who developed several clean, non-annotated Java POJO domain models. Every domain model contains about 15-50 classes. So far, these Java POJO domain models have only been used in Android apps. 
For a new project my client is undertaking, it is necessary to use these domain models server side, and save the instances of their classes to a sql database.

We will use JPA for this. Since the jar needs to be reused in the existing Android apps, using JPA annotations is not an option. So, I need to create JPA xml mappings for these 100+ classes.

**I was wondering: is it possible to auto generate JPA Xml mappings from clean Java classes/POJOs using some lib/tool? When I started looking, I thought I was going to find a "javamodel 2 jpa xml mapping" tool pretty quick, but so far, no luck, and I have already been looking for a while.**

To me, it seems like a tool that would be useful in tons of scenarios, so I almost can't believe it doesn't exist.

I know about tools such as hbm2java. I know it is possible to create POJOS/orm mapping from a ddl and POJOS/DDL from an orm mapping. But I need the orm mapping given the POJOs.

Also, I know a JPA xml mapping can be pretty short and simple/basic properties are auto mapped. I realize I won't have to map every single property, but still, I am facing a lot of repetitive work if such a tool does not exist.

**So, does a "javamodel 2 jpa xml mapping" tool exist?**

Comment: It is possible to create a stub JPA annotation class that can be shimmed in on Android? That removes the "clean" POJO aspect, but would allow direct annotations, perhaps ..

Comment: Yeah, but it would clutter the model a bit and my client does not want to do this. They don't even know for sure they will stay with jpa/sql in the long run. Anyway, even assuming that annotations are an option, the problem still exists: I could not find a "javamodel 2 jpa annotated javamodel" tool either.

Answer (score 4):

I created a simple tool for this, hosted at Github: https://github.com/IntegratingStuff/java2jpa

Basic usage example:

```
Java2JpaMappingGenerator java2JpaMappingGenerator = 
   new Java2JpaMappingGenerator(); 
java2JpaMappingGenerator.setRenderJpaMappingForClassStrategy(
   new RenderJpaMappingForClassStrategyDefaultImpl()); 
JpaMappingRendererDefaultImpl jpaMappingRenderer = 
   new JpaMappingRendererDefaultImpl("target/META-INF/orm.xml");
java2JpaMappingGenerator.setJpaMappingRenderer(jpaMappingRenderer);  
java2JpaMappingGenerator.generateJpaMappingsForPackages("com.test.model");
jpaMappingRenderer.createMappedFiles();
```

With this tool, you can create JPA Xml mappings from a Java POJO domain model. However, often you will need to create a custom implementation of the RenderJpaMappingForClassStrategy interface for you own model in order to use the tool efficiently.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe stupid idea but how about a batch generator creating fasade/proxy .java files with JPA @Annotation tags. Big show stopper might be your app must use JPACustomer type not real one. Just one suggestion don't kill the messenger.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="customer")
public class JPACustomer extends Customer {

  @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  public long getId() { return super.getId(); }
  public void setId(long id) { super.setId(id); }

  @Column(name="name")
  public String getName() { return super.getName(); }
  public void setName(String s) { super.setName(s); }

  // ElementCollection provides simple OneToMany linking in OpenJPA.
  // joinColumn.name=foreign key column in child table
  @ElementCollection(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
  @CollectionTable(name="cust_role", joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="cust_id")})
  @Column(name="role")
  public List<String> getRoles() { return super.getRoles(); }
  public void setRoles(List<String> roles) { super.setRoles(roles); }

  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. That would work, but creating a generator for these classes might be more work than actually making a "javamodel 2 jpa xml mapping" tool(which I will probably end up doing if none can be found).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using Eclipse's JPA support (Dali)